# How to query the last 5 records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

create a sql query to display the last 5 records of the Sdelki table by Users.ID_user the Users table is linked to the Clients table by ID_User, and the Klients table is linked to the Sdelki table by ID_Klient

this query didn't work

```
SELECT Sdelki.*
FROM Sdelki
INNER JOIN Klients
ON Sdelki.ID_Klient = Klients.ID_Klient
INNER JOIN Users
ON Klients.ID_user = Users.ID_user
ORDER BY Sdelki.ID_sdelki DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

using SQL Server

Comment: What was wrong with the results produced by this query?

Comment: What do you mean by "this query didn't work"?

Comment: ...and how is "last N records" defined in your table? Contrary to what many people assume, RDBMS like SQL Server don't actually keep track of record insertion order or track other metadata (Sqlite is the exception): so you can only do that if you have an `IDENTITY` column that is _never_ reset, or you have a `Created datetime2` column which is _never_ arbitrarily overwritten.

Comment: SQL Server has TOP, or FETCH FIRST, instead of LIMIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql Server doesn't use `LIMIT`, it uses [`TOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead :

```
SELECT TOP (5) Sdelki.*
FROM Sdelki
INNER JOIN Klients
ON Sdelki.ID_Klient = Klients.ID_Klient
INNER JOIN Users
ON Klients.ID_user = Users.ID_user
ORDER BY Sdelki.ID_sdelki DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Klients.ID_user` or `Users.ID_user` in order by clause to get the expected results.

```
SELECT
    TOP 5 Sdelki.*
FROM 
    Sdelki
INNER JOIN 
    Klients
ON 
    Sdelki.ID_Klient = Klients.ID_Klient
INNER JOIN 
    Users
ON 
    Klients.ID_user = Users.ID_user
ORDER BY 
    Klients.ID_user DESC;
```

This is the updated query

**EDIT:** removed `LIMIT 5` and used `TOP 5` in the query, since LIMIT isn't supported in SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a LIMIT clause as the other correct answer calls out.

Comment: gives an error message:
wrong syntax near LIMIT construct

Comment: ohh, apologies for the confusion, @MadRadiator